# Web application, Update members status to other member

Tags: c#, javascript, web-applications, postback, observer-pattern

i want to make something like a friend status if he is online or offline.

c# code behind, javascript , html5

There is a similar question but it uses .php and i dont know anything about php.

Anyway I was thinking that for the online, you can track when the user has actually logged on.(turn a field in the DB for online to true)

But how do you send that info to the person who needs to know if the other user logged in? can the codebehind or the js have like a receiving function/method that is called when he gets online?(like an observer pattern?)

also then when it updates we dont want a whole page refresh but the least possible @flickering for the page. post-back?

Finally to track if the user is offline it could be like a http response to check for a responce from the online user if he is still online. But how? :P

If we finally get that its offline can we use the same receiving function/method that we informed the other person that he was online?

Any help would be much appriciated. Hope this could become a reference for similar threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But how do you send that info to the person who needs to know if the other user logged in?

You can't send the information to the user. He must get the information himself. What I mean is that http is a "pull protocol", which means that you can't push information to the client, you just give him what he requests.

Now, what you want is the client to request the information without noticing the fact that his browser is sending requests. The best way to do this is to use **Ajax** in javascript to send a request to a **web service**. This way, you can get information from your server without doing any postbacks. Then, to give an impression of live information, you'll want to set your ajax call in a setTimeout to get the information any given time interval (30 seconds, 1 minute, your choice).

To simplify - a lot - your ajax calls, have a look at [Jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

If you don't know any of this, don't give up, it may look more complicated than it actually is.

> Finally to track if the user is offline

What I suggest is that you keep track of every request from that user, and after a certain time without any request, you declare this user as logged out.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So using an ajax it will make the request to "get" the status of the other user. but if you want to display that information on the web app then you  need a postback to change the status to online or offline right?

Comment: Your ajax call will receive the status, then you do what you want with it in javascript. Facebook turns a little dot to green next to a username for example.

Comment: Also I dont know much about javascript but if you set a timer, do you need anything like a new thread or its irrelevant? I mean what happens if you have another javascript function bound to a button? will it cause any issues?

Comment: It works pretty much by itself, see setInterval here : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp . There is no multithreading in javascript, but functions like that will "simulate" it.

Comment: I am familiar with the timer in javascript i just didnt know what happened with Threads, well thanks a lot for all the info!